# Use an ArrayList in Java on JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I am trying to pass an ArrayList that I have created to a JSP page but I am having a difficult time attempting to do this. Here is what I have so far.

Java Class:

```
public class Main {

    private ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public Main (){
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lang.txt"));
            String line;
            String[] employee;
            Employee employeeObject;
            br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               employee = line.split(",");
               employeeObject = new Employee (employee[0], employee[1], employee[2], employee[3], employee[4], employee[5], employee[6]);
               employees.add(employeeObject);             
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){

        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the employees
     */
    public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    /**
     * @param employees the employees to set
     */
    public void setEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

JSP Page:

```
<%@page import="lab3final.beans.Employee"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="employee" scope="session" class="lab3final.beans.Main"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Table Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Data in text file in table format</h1><br>
        <c:forEach items="${employee.employees}" var="item">
            ${item}<br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

It would be great if someone could give me some idea on what I am doing wrong. I am not able to read the ArrayList I created on my JSP page.

UPDATE: I figured out the problem was that I had to give the full path to my text file `lang.txt` otherwise it would be searching for the file in some other directory which was not my main project directory. I guess this is the default location for searching for files when I try to read files using a FileReader in the constructor of a class.

Right now I can print out all the employees using `${employee.employees}` and it will print out all the employees using the `toString()` method I have defined in the employees class. I am still trying to figure out how I can use the loop function in JSP so I can loop through each individual employee.

Comment: There's nothing in the list?  Could you confirm that by placing `<c:out value="${employee.employees.size}" />` before you attempt to loop?

Comment: What's the "link" between the java class and the jsp? Struts2?? What? How? Where is it deployed at all?

Comment: Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You can also test with `<c:if test="${empty employee.employees)}">... </c:if>`

Comment: Your employees variable is private

Comment: Try to simplify the initialization in constructor (some hard-coding), then try again.

Comment: @Makoto Yes the list is empty. `<c:out value="${employee.employees.size}" />` gives me `NumberFormatException` error. This is being deployed on a glassfish server and I believe the link between the java class and jsp is this line `<jsp:useBean id="employee" scope="session" class="lab3final.beans.Main"/>` in on my JSP page but I am not exactly sure. I am fairly new to JSP.

Comment: No, the size is not an appropriate function, try adding a getter in Main class, which gives size. For example, public int getEmployeesSize() { return employees.size(); }  
And in JSP, <c:out value="${employee.employeesSize}" />

Comment: @User49234123412341 yes, that prints out the size as 0. However, `<c:out value="${employee.employeesSize}" />` does not work, I have to use just `${employee.employeesSize}`. Also, as @curiosu suggested, if I hardcode an employee object and add it to the ArrayList, I am able to read it on the JSP page. I guess the issue has to do something with reading the data from a file?

Comment: There you go, print the data in the txt file, first to your console, then worry about printing to jsp. Or may be Debug would be easy.

Comment: And use `ReflectionToStringBuilder` from commons-lang jar to create  toString, don't generate or reinvent a wheel.

Comment: This isn't a code review forum, but I'd suggest another thing, use finally block to call `br.close()` seems more appropriate, in case it fails at some point of your code, it's ensured to be released.

Comment: @User49234123412341 thanks for all your suggestions, they were really helpful. I figured out that the problem is at the line `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lang.txt"));` which throws an `IOException`. I am not sure why this is happening because I was able to read the  file before using the same statement and also print the file to the console. The file exists in the project directory.

Comment: Ok the error is that its not able to find the file `lang.txt` even though `lang.txt` exists in the main project directory.

Comment: It works now, I had to give it the exact path to the text file. `${employee.employees}` prints out all the employees. I need to figure out how to go through each employee because the loop in my original post doesn't seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. It was a silly mistake on my part. I forgot to add this line on top of the JSP page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

This is why the `forEach` loop did not work. Once I added that line to the top of my page, the loop worked perfectly fine and I was able to loop through each individual employee object. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

call each variable of your employee class in your jsp page. Make sure that your employee object has all your necessary getter and setters. ${item.variable1}, ${item.variable2}

Comment: My constructor is called otherwise I would see any empty list on my JSP page. But in this case, when I print `${employee.employees}`, I get a list of all the employees. I just need to figure out how to loop through each individual employee so I can print it out correctly in a table format on the JSP page.

Comment: My Employee class has all the getters and setters. For example, one variable is called `first` and it has and set method for it and the get method for it. However, I do not have access to the `first` variable on the JSP page.